# C programming - Why isn't this signal being ignored?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am writing a program that every 5 seconds sends a signal (alarm) to itself. I also want that if a user types in terminal "kill -ALRM PID" that is ignored. If I understand the signal calls, my program should do that, however, when I use that command from terminal the proram thinks it is one of its alarms and doesnt ignore it

```
int s = 0;
void alarm_func(int s) {
    s = s + 10;
    char buff[256];
    sprintf(buff, "ALARM pid=%d, %d seconds, getpid(), s);
    write(1, buff, strlen(buff));    
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int k = 1; //just a different value from 0
    if (k == 0) signal(SIGALRM, alarm_func);
    else signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN); //this should ignore the terminal-created alarm (?)
    while (s<100) {
        k = alarm(10);
        pause();
    }  
    exit(1);
}
```

Thanks a lot

EDIT: My prgram is supposed to send a signal to itself every 10 seconds for 100 seconds, i.e., 10 times. BUT, i also want that IF I TRY TO SEND A SIGNAL TO THE PROGRAM FROM THE TERMINAL (kill -ALRM 'pid') THAT SIGNAL GETS IGNORED. This is why I use the variable k: if I send the signal from terminal, k will be different to 0 (since the 10 secons from the alarm(10) didnt fully occur) so the signal will get ignored (signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN)).

This is how I understand the usage of signals, starting to realize I know close to nothing

Sorry for all the potential ambiguities

Comment: k is uninitialized and is likely not equal to zero.

Comment: What's the point of that `if` branch on uninitialized `k`? And how is that related to `signal`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, alarm() returns 0 if the full time has transcurred, and otherwise (when the alrm happens by terminal) it returns the amount of time left. I tried initializing k = 1 but it didnt work either.

Comment: Maybe this should be done in a completely different way, i dont know

Comment: But the value of `k` is tested before the return value of `alarm` is assigned to it.

Comment: In that case it should go to the else branch and just do nothing?

Comment: "*I tried initializing k = 1 but it didnt work either.*" What did not work either?

Comment: However the code reads an uninitalised variable, which invokes undefined behaviour, though *anything* could happen.

Comment: Ok i will add an EDIT section to the post trying to answer all these questions as well as i can.

Comment: EDIT has been added.

Comment: "This is why I use the variable k: if I send the signal from terminal, k will be different to 0" - `k` is only used at program startup. how could it change anything?

Comment: Yes, you seem to have a very confused understanding of how programs execute. This `if ( k == 0 )` stuff doesn't set up some kind of persistent relation where any time `k == 0` the signal is ignored, and any time `k != 0` the signal is handled - it just tests it once at the beginning, the signal handler is registered, and the value `k` then plays no further part in your program.

Comment: How could it be done then? to ignore the signals that the user sends from terminal?

Comment: @Ruben: If you register your signal handler with `sigaction()`, then you can write a signal handler which accepts a pointer to a `siginfo_t` struct as its second argument. The members of this struct contain, among others, `si_code`, which will be set to `SI_USER` if the signal was sent with `kill()`, `SI_TIMER` if it was the result an expired POSIX timer, and some other options. You can't ignore the signal entirely this way, but your signal handler can determine the source and, for instance, take no action if `si_code` contains `SI_USER`.

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate between the signal sent by `alarm()`, and the signal sent by `kill` at the terminal, by registering your signal handler with `sigaction()`. This will allow you to write a signal handler that gets a lot more information, specifically one that accepts a pointer to a `struct siginfo_t` which contains enough information for you to determine where the signal came from.

Here's an example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

sig_atomic_t s = 0;

void handler(int signum, siginfo_t * si, void * ucon) {
    switch ( si->si_code ) {
        case SI_USER:
            printf("Ignoring signal from user, s is %lu...\n",
                   (unsigned long) s);
            break;

        case SI_KERNEL:
            s += 10;
            printf("Processing signal from alarm(), s is %lu...\n",
                   (unsigned long) s);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Ignoring signal from unknown source, s is %lu...\n",
                   (unsigned long) s);
            break;
    }
}


int main(void) {

    /*  Set up struct sigaction  */

    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = NULL;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

    /*  Register signal handler  */

    if ( sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL) == -1 ) {
        perror("Couldn't register signal handler.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /*  Go into alarm loop  */

    while ( s < 100 ) {
        alarm(10);
        pause();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that we don't normally perform IO in signal handlers, so this is for demonstration purposes only.

Sample output:

```
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ ./alarm &
[1] 2042
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ ps | grep alarm
 2042 pts/0    00:00:00 alarm
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ Processing signal from alarm(), s is 10...
kill -ALRM 2042
Ignoring signal from user, s is 10...
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ Processing signal from alarm(), s is 20...
kill -ALRM 2042
Ignoring signal from user, s is 20...
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ kill -ALRM 2042
Ignoring signal from user, s is 20...
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ kill -9 2042
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ 
[1]+  Killed                  ./alarm
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$
```

In this case, the signals sent by `alarm()` have an `si_code` of `SI_KERNEL`, whereas the ones sent via `kill()` (or the `kill` command at the terminal, same thing) have an `si_code` of `SI_USER`, so you can tell the source.

Obviously you have to actually receive the signal first to find this info out, so you can't actually ignore it based on source. In general this is fine, but in your case it causes problems because you use `pause()` to separate your calls to `alarm()`, and `pause()` will return after *any* signal that is caught. So although you can de facto ignore `kill()` signals in your handler, it'll still trigger another alarm in ten seconds time, because that's how your main loop works. You'll still get exactly ten signals sent by `alarm()`, and you'll be able to handle only those ten, but the timing of them will be affected by terminal use of `kill`.

The obvious solution to this is, of course, not to use `pause()` for this purpose. If you want to use a timer like this, then just use a regular POSIX timer, and you won't suffer from this problem. You could cobble an alternative way around it, but it's pointless doing so when you can just use a regular POSIX timer.

Comment: You should not call printf() from within a signal handler. (The OP did not make this misstake)

Comment: @wildplasser: Is there something about "Note that we don't normal perform IO in signal handlers, so this is for demonstration purposes only" that wasn't clear?

Comment: No, it still is wrong. Even for demonstration purposes. Future readers might reuse your snippet (because it *looks* solid) , ignoring the text.

Comment: @wildplasser: Stuff and nonsense.

Comment: @wildplasser: That's a rather naive and simplistic view. Functions which are not "async-safe" are fine if you can guarantee they won't be interrupted, which in this program is true since only the signal handler calls `printf()` and it can't be interrupted by a second `SIGALRM`, so it doesn't need to be re-entrant. Even reentrant functions are often not safe to use for other reasons - calls to `write()` in a signal handler can still cause problems with garbage or out-of-order output if the main program is in the middle of `write()`ing stuff to the same file, for instance.